# Sparse Matrix Addition

Tags: python, scipy

I am using a sparse matrix format implemented in scipy as csr_matrix. I have a mat variable which is in csr_matrix format and all its elements are non-negative. However, when I use mat + mat operation, the non-zero element number decreases which is quite strange to me. What  want is a element-wise addition but why the non-element number will decreases as each of the element is non-negative.

Best Regards

Comment: Your question lacks detail, so in my answer I had to make assumptions. I recommend editing your question to add code demonstrating your problem. That will likely get you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nnz` member of `csr_matrix` in SciPy counts explicit zeros, so depending on how you create your matrix, this may explain what you are observing. You can see this behavior by explicitly setting zeros in a matrix.

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> A = csr_matrix((5, 5))
>>> A.nnz
0
>>> A[0, 0] = 0
>>> A.nnz
1
>>> A[1,1] = 0
>>> A.nnz
2
```

Now when you do an operation that creates a new matrix (such as matrix addition), the explicit zeros are not retained.

```
>>> B = A + A
>>> B.nnz
0
```

Answer (score 0):

although it might be a bit over kill and not related it may be worth looking into these two libraries

[petsc4py](http://code.google.com/p/petsc4py/)

[petsc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/)

will just about solve any sparse matrix problem you can think of

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @talonmies well its worth checking out if he ever want's to use standard software to solve a scale of scientific problems that scipy will never be able to without agreat deal of effort, i should have put this as a comment and not a question sorry for that